# Why is this statement within a while loop never executed?

Tags: c

I've written some code to right justify all the bits in a char's byte.
However, the application is stuck in a loop because it never executes the line `positionmask<<1;`

Why is this happening?

```
void rjustify(char thisChar)
{
    unsigned char c = thisChar;
    unsigned char positionmask = 1;
    unsigned char insertionmask = 1;
    while(positionmask)
    {
            if(c & positionmask)
            {
                    c^=positionmask;
                    c|=insertionmask;
                    insertionmask<<=1;
            }
            positionmask<<1; //This line is never executed.
    }
    printf("%c", &c);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When the line is executed, it has no effect.  Turn up your compiler warnings and change it to:

```
   positionmask <<= 1;
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to do this: `positionmask <<= 1;` instead!

The compiler never produces buggy code. unless the compiler that produced the compiler is buggy.

Answer (score 2):

it is executed, it is a noop

positionmask <<= 1;

Note to self: do not rush to make comments, it creates spam.